# My Add-On was approved by Google, but it is available only to members of my employer's domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-script-addon

I developed an add-on for Google spreadsheets, have sent it over to Google for a review, and after much blood, toil, tears and sweat, had it successfully approved.

Yet, the add-on is only available for members on my employer's domain - a domain that uses Google tools and services (mail services are Gmail based, for example). My employer and I want it to be available to anyone with a Google account. When I contacted Google on the issue, they have sent me a link to a support page in which there are departments of support. My inquiry fits none of them.

Could any of you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What did you set as "Visibilty"?

Comment: Where is this setting located in the Google cloud console? I've searched for it and got no results.

Comment: If you plan on opening up the add-on to users outside your employer's domain, and you're using restricted scopes (all related to gmail), your add-on will need to undergo a security assessment which you'll have to pay for (between US$15K and US$75K). See [User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy) and [Security Assessment](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#security-assessment).

Comment: @Dimu Only if the data is stored on third party servers.. Right?

Comment: @Dimu The add-on processes data extracted from a user's spreadsheet and generates a file which is saved on his Google drive. Will such a payment still be involved?

Comment: @Mr.Programmer As long as your add-on does not leverage any [restricted scopes](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes) then you should be good.

Comment: Even if your add-on uses restricted scopes, that won't prevent it from being published publicly.  But, a published add-on with restricted scopes, *that hasn't been verified* has a quota of 100 new users.  But, your question is about visibility.  Using restricted scopes, and not being verified should *not* affect visibility.  With that being said, it can be difficult to get answers about what the problem really is.  There isn't enough characters here to explain how to navigate the Google Cloud Platform for G Suite add-on publishing, but that's what we really need.

Comment: It might be better to ask your question on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) as far as the appropriateness of the question according to the guidelines of this site.  If you do post a question there, please give the link in the comments.

Comment: @SandyGood Where can I find documentation detailing the 100 user quota for non-verified apps?

Comment: @DimuDesigns Here is the link.  [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865) Scroll down to "OAuth user quotas"

Comment: @SandyGood https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125943/my-add-on-was-approved-by-google-but-it-is-available-only-to-members-of-my-empl By the way, my add-on has been verified.